# How to insert user with existing role-object using EF?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I  have a class with following structure

```
class Role
{
   public int Id{get;set;}
   public string RoleName{get;set;}
}

class User 
{

public int Id{get;set;}
public virtual Role Role{get;set;}
public string Name{get;set;}


}
```

When ever i insert a new user with existing role, EF creating a new Role entity with all the same values expect Id.  The code i am using to insert is given bellow

```
void InsertUser(User user){

// The role of this user is already populated with values which available in DB

var context=new demoContext();

context.Users.Add(user);
context.SaveChanges();

}
```

NB: I tried attached state

My question is how i can  inform EF to use the existing entity rather than creating new if the entity have same key ?

```
// Edit


in my controller 

public jsonResult Saveuser(string name,int roleId){

// populating users from controller

var role=_roleRepo.FindById(roleId);

var user =new User{ Name=name,Role=role};




}
```

Comment: how you populate your user object, can you show please

Comment: @Mak please check the edited portion

Comment: Please check in your database if User has role id as foreign key or not

Comment: @Mak i double checked that . yes  user has a foreign key with RoleId

Answer (score 0):

You can add one more property to your User class

```
public int RoleId {get; set;}
```

And then create your user object something like this :

```
var user = new User(){ Name = "user1", RoleId = "your existing role Id" };
```